# How to create SQLLDR Control File that handles a text file containing rows which are broken?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

So for example, the text file containing the data to be loaded might look like this:

```
$ cat employee.txt
100,Thomas,Sales,5000
200,Jason,Technology,5500
300,Mayla,
Technology,7000
400,Nisha,Marke
ting,9500
500,Randy,Technology,
6000
501,Ritu,Accounting,5400
```

You can see that some of the rows contain a line break at the wrong point. One of them even breaks in the middle of the actual string. As a result, I receive an error when trying to run the SQL loader.

So I was wondering if there was any parameter I could add to the load or control file that can handle such a messy data file. I was thinking if there might be a way to count the n'th comma in the text file to determine when the next row should begin.

Comment: Edit: One of the records in the example was changed to show further example of where the lines of the text file breaks. See record example: 400,Nisha,Marke
ting,9500

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a different record separator and then append the separator to the end of each "row" of the input file. Something like:

sqlldr.ctl:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INFILE employee.txt "str ' 0X1E\n'"
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE <table name>
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    ...
)
```

employee.txt:

```
100,Thomas,Sales,5000 0X1E
200,Jason,Technology,5500 0X1E
300,Mayla,
Technology,7000 0X1E
400,Nisha,Marketing,9500 0X1E
500,Randy,Technology,
6000 0X1E
501,Ritu,Accounting,5400 0X1E
```

Note that in this example the ' 0X1E' is a text string and not the hexadecimal value of 0X1E (ASCII record separator character) which I could never get to work right...

Comment: This was just a small example. Generally I receive records containing hundreds of thousands of rows. I wouldn't think it's too practical to append every single row with the ASCII separator. Is there another solution? Note: I added a minor edit to the text file example.

Comment: @Phillip - That's the solution that I ended up using, but then I'm also creating the loader files. I'm also not an sqlldr expert. Given that you're getting these files from elsewhere, how do/would you determine where the end of each record is at?

Comment: Usually it goes by the number of columns that exist. So if there are 15 columns, for example, then the last field in a row comes after the 15'th terminator. That's why I was wondering if there was a way to determine when the n'th comma or whatever terminator occurred in a data file and if you could condition this with some type of parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CONTINUEIF` clause in your control file. This forces `sqlldr` to look at the last character, and if it matches the string (comma in your example), it will concatenate the next line to the current line before continuing.  [Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8A07D429-7BF0-49F6-9329-91BC1AB80C98.htm#SUTIL1102)

```
load data
infile 'testdata.dat'
continueif last = ','
into table testtable
truncate 
fields terminated by ',' 
(
empid,
ename,
dept,
salary 
)
```

EDIT based on new info. Let's start at the source.  Can you require the source fix this before sending?  If a vendor, lean on them to not send garbage data!  If from a source program, the dept should be picked from a list, not entered freehand where the user could press enter or who knows what else.  That said, if you have to deal with what you are given (we've all been there), you will have to pre-process this data somehow before loading.  It's a slippery slope as you'll have to come up with rules on how to detect the break is in the middle of a word.

Maybe an awk or sed script that looks at each line and if the last set of characters after the last comma do not meet the rules for what the column should contain, assume the line is broken and concatenate the next line?  You'll have to do some analysis to determine of that logic will work for you.

Comment: This is honestly really great! But I've realized in the text file one of the records breaks the actual string, so the line ends with half of the string text and the next line is the other half. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Edit your original post and add an example to your test data.  Include a comment to indicate the change.

Comment: Done. See the example record: 400,Nisha,Marketing,9500

Comment: See new comments.